# 'use fusion builder' is not appearing in wordpress Avada theme

Tags: wordpress

I have installed the AVADA theme's plugin Fusion Builder. System status is all ok.
but when I'm going to add a new page. It is not showing the 'use fusion builder' option.
I am done with updating the wordpress and all other plugins.
I have also tried making Fusion builder auto activation on. Still its not working.

Comment: Can you please check whether the Gutenberge is installed or not?

Comment: No. Gutenberge is not installed.

Comment: WordPress Version ?

Comment: initially I have installed 5.0.3 but it asks for updating it to 5.1 everytime. So its 5.1.

Comment: Its gutenberge is already integrated with WP Version 5.0 and above.

Comment: Please check my answer, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Fusion Builder is enabled in **Fusion Builder > Settings**. Under **Post Types**, check the box next to the post types (post, page, etc.) with which you want to use Fusion Builder.

Comment: they are checked.

Comment: Have you registered your purchase?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Gutenberge Block editor may be the resons for your problem. The following code will de-register the block editor to re-solve the issue. 
Please add the script to the **functions.php** : **after_setup_theme** action hook

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'tristup_setup' );

function tristup_setup()
{
    add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false', 10);
    // disable for post types
    add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post_type', '__return_false', 10);
}
```

hope this will solve your problem.